# My routes has resources :home, but rspec is saying routes not defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

My homecontroller has:

```
def about()
end
```

And I have a rspec test that does GET 'about' and it fails saying that there is no route that matches.

doesn't this map all actions in the controller:

```
resources :home
```

or do I have to explicitly state each action in the home controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resources :home` sets up the default RESTful routes - index, show, new, create, edit, update, and destroy.  Any additional routes have to be specified.  It looks like you're adding a simple collection route, so you'd specify it like this:

```
resources :home
  collection do
    get 'about'
  end
end
```

This will give your the route '/home/about'.  I assume this is Rails 3.  If you're in Rails 2.x, do it like so:

```
map.resources :home, :collection => {:about => :get}
```

And from the command line, you can always see what routes you have available with this command:

```
rake routes
```

I hope this helps!

**EDIT:** If you want a default route, you can add this:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
```

This is a default route that will match any generic requests.

**FULL ARTICLE:** Routing in Rails 3 is its own beast. There have been a lot of questions about it lately, so I've created a very detailed article with code samples to help others:

[Routing in Ruby on Rails 3](http://kconrails.com/2010/12/02/routing-in-ruby-on-rails-3/)

I created a companion Rails 3 app that can be downloaded to play around with, as well:

https://github.com/kconrails/rails3_routing

If you have any questions, please hit up my site and ask.  Thanks!

Comment: there should be a way to wire them all up automatically, surprised there isn't a way to do that...

Comment: does this give me a url helper about_homes_path?

Comment: sorry, just read your other question.  check `rake routes`, it does give you the route you asked about.  Using the default route I listed above doesn't.  So there's another good reason to use explicit routing.

Answer (score 0):

resources will give you the 7 CRUD methods for a controller, if you want additional actions, you need to do something like the following:

```
resources :homes do 
  collection do
    match "about" => "homes#about", :as => "about"
  end
end
```

Then you'll also have an additional about_homes_path/url helper available.